# How to identify objects in a Vec based on their references?

Tags: rust

I have the following problem: there is a Vec, a list of Stmt (statement) objects. Then computations on vectors of references to statements (Vec<&Stmt>) identify 2 disjoint subsets (A and B) of the original set. But now the subsets are expressed in terms of references and not the original objects.
I would like to end up with 3 vectors of Stmt, corresponding to subsets A, B, and S - A - B.
I hope this is possible w/o bending over backwards, like inventing integer indices of all elements (and expressing subsets by sets of indices).

Comment: This is very tricky, because the vector holding the references prevents modification of the vector holding the objects.

Comment: I think your question is very abstract, would you mind writing a code example that serves as an acceptance criteria on which we can check whether our response answers your question?

Comment: I have a feeling that this might be an XY problem where the actual thing that should be fixed is that there shouldn't be a vector of references in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

> I hope this is possible w/o bending over backwards

I'm afraid not, with the information you give us now.
The problem is that `Vec<&Stmt>` has no information about where the original `Stmt` lives. Yes, it knows its address and that it's not movable right now (as it is borrowed), but apart of that, it has no knowledge about the fact that it is in a list.

Therefore, to take the elements out of the original list, you would have to match them to the `Vec<&Stmt>`s first.

Then you have the problem that the `Vec<&Stmt>`s borrow from the original list and therefore make the original list immutable until the borrow is returned.

The only solutions I see without changing the algorithm to return something else than `Vec<&Stmt>` are all very dirty hacks.

You *could* iterate through the original list and remember for every item whether it was in `A`, `B` or neither via comparing every element to the entire `Vec<&Stmt>`s via `std::ptr::eq`. But that would be horribly slow as it is `O(n^2)`.

You could do better via converting the `Vec<&Stmt>` to `HashSet<*const Stmt>` whilst holding the original one, to make sure `Vec<Stmt>` doesn't get moved and all the pointers invalidated. Then, a lookup in the HashSets of whether an item is in `A` or `B` is armortized `O(1)`, making the entire thing `O(n)`.
But I don't think it'll get better than that without changing the output of your computations.

Here is an example code that implements the `O(n)` solution:

```rust
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn magical_algorithm(data: &[Stmt]) -> (Vec<&Stmt>, Vec<&Stmt>) {
    let left = data.iter().take(2).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    let right = data.iter().rev().take(2).collect::<Vec<_>>();

    (left, right)
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Stmt(i32);

fn main() {
    let vec = vec![Stmt(0), Stmt(1), Stmt(2), Stmt(3), Stmt(4), Stmt(5)];
    let (a, b) = magical_algorithm(&vec);

    // Store the size of a and b, for later
    let a_len = a.len();
    let b_len = b.len();

    println!("Original data: {:?}", vec);
    println!("A: {:?}", a);
    println!("B: {:?}", b);

    // Convert a into addresses
    let a_ptrs = a
        .iter()
        .map(|&el| el as *const Stmt)
        .collect::<HashSet<_>>();
    let b_ptrs = b
        .iter()
        .map(|&el| el as *const Stmt)
        .collect::<HashSet<_>>();

    // Use address sets to perform a fast lookup for whether an element is in A or B
    let contained_in = vec
        .iter()
        .map(|el| {
            let el_ptr = el as *const Stmt;
            (a_ptrs.contains(&el_ptr), b_ptrs.contains(&el_ptr))
        })
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();

    // Drop a and b here to make sure they are still held while creating the
    // contained_in vector
    drop(a);
    drop(b);

    // Use contained_in to actually map vec into 3 arrays
    let mut vec_a = Vec::new();
    let mut vec_b = Vec::new();
    let mut vec_not_a_or_b = Vec::new();
    vec_a.reserve(a_len);
    vec_b.reserve(b_len);
    vec_not_a_or_b.reserve(vec.len() - (a_len + b_len));

    for (elem, (in_a, in_b)) in vec.into_iter().zip(contained_in.into_iter()) {
        match (in_a, in_b) {
            (true, _) => vec_a.push(elem),
            (false, true) => vec_b.push(elem),
            (false, false) => vec_not_a_or_b.push(elem),
        }
    }

    // Done
    println!("Elements that were in A: {:?}", vec_a);
    println!("Elements that were in B: {:?}", vec_b);
    println!("Elements that were neither in A or B: {:?}", vec_not_a_or_b);
}
```

```
Original data: [Stmt(0), Stmt(1), Stmt(2), Stmt(3), Stmt(4), Stmt(5)]
A: [Stmt(0), Stmt(1)]
B: [Stmt(5), Stmt(4)]
Elements that were in A: [Stmt(0), Stmt(1)]
Elements that were in B: [Stmt(4), Stmt(5)]
Elements that were neither in A or B: [Stmt(2), Stmt(3)]
```

---

### Caveat

While pointer arithmetic and comparison is not unsafe, this code might behave unexpectedly if the Vector gets moved in the process.

Using pointers like this is correct in the existing case, but it is still dangerous in general and ill-advised.

---

### Adding more capabilities to the `Stmt` struct

I suspect this is an XY-problem. The reason why this is so hard is because `Stmt` is non-copyable, non-comparable and non-hashable.
Adding those three properties to `Stmt` makes this entire problem immensely easier:

```rust
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn magical_algorithm<T>(data: &[T]) -> (Vec<&T>, Vec<&T>) {
    let left = data.iter().take(2).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    let right = data.iter().rev().take(2).collect::<Vec<_>>();

    (left, right)
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Hash, PartialEq, Eq)]
struct Stmt(i32);

fn main() {
    let vec = vec![Stmt(0), Stmt(1), Stmt(2), Stmt(3), Stmt(4), Stmt(5)];
    let (a, b) = magical_algorithm(&vec);

    println!("Original data: {:?}", vec);
    println!("A: {:?}", a);
    println!("B: {:?}", b);

    let set_all: HashSet<Stmt> = vec.iter().cloned().collect();
    let set_a: HashSet<Stmt> = a.into_iter().cloned().collect();
    let set_b: HashSet<Stmt> = b.into_iter().cloned().collect();
    let set_a_b: HashSet<Stmt> = set_a.union(&set_b).cloned().collect();
    let set_not_a_or_b: HashSet<Stmt> = set_all.difference(&set_a_b).cloned().collect();

    // Done
    println!("Elements that were in A: {:?}", set_a);
    println!("Elements that were in B: {:?}", set_b);
    println!("Elements that were neither in A or B: {:?}", set_not_a_or_b);
}
```

---

### The underlying problem

The reason why we have to go through all these things is that `magical_algorithm` discards positional information by returning references.

Consider the case where `magical_algorithm` would return *indices* instead:

```rust
fn magical_algorithm<'a>(data: &[Stmt]) -> (Vec<usize>, Vec<usize>) {
    let left = data
        .iter()
        .enumerate()
        .filter_map(|(pos, el)| if el.0 < 2 { Some(pos) } else { None })
        .collect();
    let right = data
        .iter()
        .enumerate()
        .filter_map(|(pos, el)| if el.0 > 3 { Some(pos) } else { None })
        .collect();

    (left, right)
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Stmt(i32);

fn main() {
    let vec = vec![Stmt(0), Stmt(1), Stmt(2), Stmt(3), Stmt(4), Stmt(5)];
    let (mut a, mut b) = magical_algorithm(&vec);

    println!("Original data: {:?}", vec);
    println!("A(indices): {:?}", a);
    println!("B(indices): {:?}", b);

    // Initialize the output arrays
    let mut vec_a = Vec::new();
    let mut vec_b = Vec::new();
    let mut vec_not_a_or_b = Vec::new();
    vec_a.reserve(a.len());
    vec_b.reserve(b.len());
    vec_not_a_or_b.reserve(vec.len() - (a.len() + b.len()));

    // Convert A and B vectors into sorted iterators
    a.sort();
    b.sort();
    let mut a_iter = a.into_iter().peekable();
    let mut b_iter = b.into_iter().peekable();

    for (pos, el) in vec.into_iter().enumerate() {
        // Retrieve if the current element is in A or B
        let in_a = a_iter.peek() == Some(&pos);
        let in_b = b_iter.peek() == Some(&pos);

        // Advance the A or B iterator if necessary
        if in_a {
            a_iter.next();
        }
        if in_b {
            b_iter.next();
        }

        // Sort the element into the respective output vector
        if in_a {
            vec_a.push(el);
        } else if in_b {
            vec_b.push(el);
        } else {
            vec_not_a_or_b.push(el);
        }
    }

    // Done
    println!("Elements that were in A: {:?}", vec_a);
    println!("Elements that were in B: {:?}", vec_b);
    println!("Elements that were neither in A or B: {:?}", vec_not_a_or_b);
}
```

This would make the problem much more trivial.

Comment: Lookup in a HashSet isn't log(N)

Comment: @Finomnis This is a beautiful answer, very similar to the solution I have been coming up with for this problem.In fact, better than my solution which involves linear search for matches, instead of a HashSet. Still, coming to Rust from Java, Scala, C/C++, etc. I am noting that this normally easy problem is hard to code in Rust. I do not think the original problem is an XY problem either. The subset A is identified among multiple candidates via optimization. These candidates are represented as sets of references to elements of the original set. Then you pick the 'best' one and move the orig objs

Comment: @JacekAmbroziak I partially disagree. I the exact problem you posted would be a problem in C++ as well. The only reason it wouldn't be a problem in Java is because in Java everything is a reference counted pointer. Which is of course possible in Rust as well, if you'd use something like `Rc` or `Arc` as the data type. 
The only reason why this is easier in C++ is because everything by default is copyable. This can be done in rust if you implement `Clone` for `Stmt`.

Comment: Again, I think this is an XY problem, if you'd use a different datatype to begin with, it wouldn't be a problem at all. You only run into this problem because `Stmt` is not copyable. In C++, everything is copyable by default, in Java everything is a refcounted smartpointer, which is also copyable by default. Both of those are of course no problem in Rust, you just have to enable one of those for your `Stmt` type.

Comment: @JacekAmbroziak Added an example of how easy this problem would be if `Stmt` had more capabilities

Comment: @Finomnis Elsewhere in this program I have indeed made other types copyable. And in yet another place I have used Rc. But as I continue learning Rust I am becoming more ambitious and trying to avoid cloning. Instead I am searching for elegant idioms. My original problem does not require cloning. It is about identifying a subset w/i a given input set using some sort of references, even integer indices if &T is not up to the task. Imagine that cloning Stmt is VERY expensive or impossible...

Comment: @JacekAmbroziak And as soon as your algorithm gives you references back, you do require cloning to make it pretty. This isn't specific to Rust. Every language that would give you back references would create the problem that you would painstakenly have to reconnect those references to the original items in the input. Either the 'algorithm' moves the items directly and returns the three sets, or you operate on indices, which would also make this super easy. The fact that the 'algorithm' disconnects output from input is the actual problem here.

Comment: Maybe try to implement the problem in C++ and link it here, so I can see what you mean. I really don't see how this would be any prettier in a different language.

Comment: Look at C++. If you had `std::vector<MyObj>`. You run a magical algorithm that tells you `MyObj*` is the chosen element. To then take the object out of the vector, the only way is to iterate over the entire vector to find the object again, as `MyObj*` does no longer carry the information at which position in the vector it is. That is the problem here, the 'algorithm' discards position information of the original objects that you need to retrieve. The 'algorithm' is the culprint here.

Comment: @JacekAmbroziak Added another example where `Stmt` has no extra capabilities, but instead the 'algorithm' returns indices instead of references. Which is a *much* simpler problem because we don't loose that information about the position in the original array.

Comment: "I suspect this is an XY-problem. The reason why this is so hard is because Stmt is non-copyable, non-comparable and non-hashable." Well, I don't want Stmt to be any of the above. Please try to imagine really large and complex structures playing the role of Stmt, eg. graphs rather than toy data structures like your wrapper for i32. For simple lightweight objects clone/eq/hash are not a problem. In some other languages I'd simply use (raw) pointers to refer to objects without copying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245061/discussion-between-finomnis-and-jacek-ambroziak).